# Why do "user-level" client mail applications typically only use SMTP for outgoing mail (and not receiving mail)?

Tags: email, smtp

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

> While electronic mail servers and other mail transfer agents use SMTP to send and receive mail messages, user-level client mail applications typically only use SMTP for sending messages to a mail server for relaying. For receiving messages, client applications usually use either the Post Office Protocol (POP) or the Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) or a proprietary system (such as Microsoft Exchange or Lotus Notes/Domino) to access their mail box accounts on a mail server.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that same page it talks about it.

> ***SMTP vs mail retrieval***
>
> SMTP is a
> delivery protocol only. It cannot pull
> messages from a remote server on
> demand. Other protocols, such as the
> Post Office Protocol (POP) and the
> Internet Message Access Protocol
> (IMAP) are specifically designed for
> retrieving messages and managing mail
> boxes. However, SMTP has a feature to
> initiate mail queue processing on a
> remote server so that the requesting
> system may receive any messages
> destined for it (cf. Remote Message
> Queue Starting). POP and IMAP are
> preferred protocols when a user's
> personal computer is only
> intermittently powered up, or Internet
> connectivity is only transient and
> hosts cannot receive message during
> off-line periods.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP was designed for use with "always on" servers; most people do not leave their mail client running 24x7 and able to receive email at all times.  More recently it became possible to use `ETRN` to instruct a remote server to try to deliver anything queued up for a client, but this is still not widely supported and in general doesn't work as well as client-side "pull" (or IMAP's fake-push `IDLE` extension).

There's an additional issue in that most servers send warnings to the original sender when delivery to the next server fails; this is a good thing for intra-server transfers but a bad thing for intermittently connected clients.